# TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed on EarthExplorer tif file

Tags: python, gdal

When trying to read the content from a .tif file off https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ I get the following error

```
ERROR 1: ZIPDecode:Decoding error at scanline 1792
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.
ERROR 1: files/original.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 7, Y offset 0: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.
```

and my code looks like this

```
def main():
    input_file = 'files/original.tif'

    ds = gdal.Open(input_file)
    raster_array = ds.ReadAsArray()

    print(raster_array)
```

The file can be viewed just fine in ArcGis Pro for example

I tried to create a copy of the file using ArcGis Pro. When creating a copy with just one raster band like the original it passed without that error but the array was full of NoData values. When I converted it to RGB however it somehow worked.

Comment: What's your question? It's often due to an invalid file (eg partial download), but it's impossible to know without the data.